# php how do I add sentence after content in string is found?

Tags: php, str-replace

Suppose I have this string.

```
$string = "While it has long been disputed, 
it's estimated that Julius Caesar was born in 
Rome on July 12 or 13, 100 BC. 
He hailed from Roman aristocrats[his family was far from rich]. 
When Caesar was 16 his father, Gaius Caesar, died. 
He remained close to his mother, Aurelia."
```

I want to search `$string` for `[his family was far from rich]` and insert into a new line `from www.wiki.com` right after `[his family was far from rich]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the content is static and you want to replace every occurrence use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

```
$search = '[his family was far from rich]';
echo str_replace($search, "\n" . $search . 'from www.wiki.com', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this?

```
$string = "While it has long been disputed, 
it's estimated that Julius Caesar was born in 
Rome on July 12 or 13, 100 BC. 
He hailed from Roman aristocrats[his family was far from rich]. 
When Caesar was 16 his father, Gaius Caesar, died. 
He remained close to his mother, Aurelia.";
```

$tofind="[his family was far from rich]";

$newstring= str_replace($tofind,$tofind." from www.wiki.com",$string);

echo $newstring;

Comment: Isn't this my answer without the new line?

Comment: Ok, you can add <br> tag inside " from www.wiki.com" like this: $newstring= str_replace($tofind,$tofind."<br> from www.wiki.com",$string);